# Bibliography title prints strange asterisk (*) after I `renewcommand`-ed the `chapter` command in `report` class

Tags: biblatex, chapters, report, renewcommand

I use `report` class for my work, and I renewed all the sectioning commands to my liking, including the `chapter` command, which apparently affects the way that biblatex prints the title of the bibliography section at the end of the work. Here is how I redefined the `chapter` command to work:

```
\renewcommand\chapter[1]{
    % Counter Step:
    \refstepcounter{chapter}
    
    % Chapter Heading:
    \begin{center}
    \textbf{\thepart\thechapter\enspace #1}
    \end{center}
    
    % Update Table of Contents:
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\normalsize\numberline{\thechapter}#1}
    \chaptermark{#1}
}
```

And this is the damage that it causes:
[image]

Suddenly, the title breaks apart into two headings: The heading “I.I. *” and the actual “Works Cited” beneath it aligned to the left in plain text. Besides, I don't want counters in my bibliography chapter, I don't know why they suddenly appear, by default “Works Cited” appears without counters. How can I renew the chapter command without breaking the bibliography title?

---

Following Frabjous' answer, I rewrote my `chapter` command to handle both starred and nonstarred versions of `chapter`. However, my `uncountedChapter` clause is being invoked as a nonstarred version of `chapter` (the opposite way) and it's incredibly confusing. Perhaps I don't understand how `@ifstar` works:

```
% The new `chapter`
\renewcommand\chapter[1]{\@ifstar\uncountedChapter\countedChapter}
% Uncounted (i.e. starred)
\newcommand\uncountedChapter[1]{
    \begin{center}
        \textbf{#1}
    \end{center}
    
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\normalsize\numberline #1}
    \chaptermark{#1}
}
% Counted (i.e. nonstarred)
\newcommand\countedChapter[1]{
    \refstepcounter{chapter}
    
    \begin{center}
        \textbf{\thepart\thechapter\enspace #1}
    \end{center}
    
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\normalsize\numberline{\thechapter}#1}
    \chaptermark{#1}
}
```

Which oddly results in:
[image]

Finally, removing the number of arguments in the new `chapter` fixes it.

```
% The new `chapter`
\renewcommand\chapter{\@ifstar\uncountedChapter\countedChapter}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, the bibliography heading created by biblatex's `\printbibliography` uses the command `\chapter*` which under its normal definition creates a chapter heading without a number. By redefining `\chapter` so it doesn't have a starred version, you've made it so the bibliography heading command essentially calls `\chapter` with the argument `*`, and then "Works Cited" just comes afterwards, no longer an argument to `\chapter`.

Luckily `biblatex` lets you change how the bibliography heading works. See the [package documentation](https://ctan.math.utah.edu/ctan/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf), p. 99. You probably want something like:

```
\defbibheading{bibliography}[Works Cited]{%
    \begin{center}
    \textbf{#1}
    \end{center}
}
```

(Maybe with or without the commands to add to the TOC.) I'll let you work out the details.

An alternative would be to use a package like [titlesec](https://ctan.org/pkg/titlesec?lang=en) to change how the sectioning commands are formatted without messing up the starred versions.

Comment: I'm now adjusting my `chapter` redefinition to handle both starred and nonstarred versions of the command. As far as I understand, a starred version of chapter is an uncounted chapter (e.g. “Works Cited”). However, when I test it with `\@ifstar{\uncountedChapter}{\countedChapter}` (new code for each subcommand) it works the other way around so that only if I swap between `uncountedChatper` and `countedChapter` then I get the result I wanted. This is incredibly confusing. Something is not right. I'll post the new code in my question so you can see what I did there.

Comment: I think I fixed it. Apparently I should not have mentioned the number of arguments in the new `chapter` command.